# What is the best way to implement trigger functionality on insert and update operation in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, triggers, crud

I have created a sample CRUD java app using MongoDB. Now I want to write triggers on insert and update operation. I have written triggers on application level but I want RDBMS like trigger functionality in Mongo. What is the best way to achieve this as there is no default trigger functionality available in MongoDB. These are available options right now:tailable cursor, oplog and iddogino/mongo-trigger. Please suggest.

Comment: If Mongo doesn't offer such functionality, and you don't want it in your application, where is this trigger supposed to live?

Comment: I could find some ways listed on official website of mongo and some other websites for achieving this functionality like tailable cursor, oplog, iddogino/mongo-trigger. As I am new to mongodb, I am not sure what exactly I need to do. Could you please explain if you have worked on these things or if there is any other way to do this?

Comment: Im trying to find out what your actual question is. Since you have the spring-data tag something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32989537/spring-data-rest-difference-between-prepersist-and-handlebeforecreate seemed to be relevant. But if you want something purely inside MongoDb, The spring-data tag seems irrelevant. Since you already know about various options your question doesn't seem to be "How can I do that", but more "What fits my needs best". So you might edit your question to clarify the question and what you actually want to do.